# TFS - How to run an app before my tests begins?

Tags: tfs, automated-tests, microsoft-test-manager

I am using Lab Center + TFS 2012 to run my automated GUI tests. I noticed that there is an option to run a script before and after the tests begin:

[image: Lab Center configuration]

- What type of scripts can I run with this option? Is it a VB script or what?
- Is it possible to run an application instead of a script?

I want to use this option to restore a Database before my tests begin, since I have 2 test agents and they connect to the same database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script can be any text file that has command line batch that saved with (.bat) extension or Powershell script, of-course you can call any exe from that file but first you will need to navigate to the path of that exe or just declar that path in the **Environment variable** of the Windows, here is an example of a file with (.bat) extension that will play the Windows Media Player.

> cd "Program Files"
>
> cd "Windows Media Player"
>
> wmplayer.exe

You can also open it and send parameters as needed.

Comment: @M-radwan-mvp Are you sure we can run Powershell scripts (ps1)? When I try, it doesn't run and MTM throws error 'The setup batch file exited with error code -1'.

Comment: I think error code -1 that's mean it can't find the command you try to run during your power shell